# Health Check with empty response and status code for Angular based project

Tags: node.js, angular

My task is to add to the angular based project one endpoint `/health_check`

This endpoint should return http status code 200 with empty body. This endpoint should not be treated as assets, scripts, styles because those are cached as I suppose. This one endpoint should not be cached at all. I have difficulties in configuring such endpoint. The purpose of this endpoint is for loadbalancer purposes only to check if server can deliver content like javascript, styles and other assets files.

I know on this one endpoint there will be no angular at all but I don't know where to configure this. When I'm running `ng serve` some server application starts that is handling all requests, and I need to know how to configure this server. Where to start? I just need to configure one route on this server.

Any advice?

Comment: If you want  to do this at the dev-server level, you can attach a route to the server exposed by [`devServer.after`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverafter).  However, in production, the actual host will vary.  Are you trying to solve at the development level or production level?

Comment: Thanks for Your comment. I'm trying to solve this on production and development level. The company is using Azure services to host this app.

Comment: Angular is a client-side technology, it does not have REST endpoints as a server application could. Node is only used during the development process 
 for serving/bundling/testing/etc via commands such as `ng serve`. Node is not used at all in production as a built Angular application is just static HTML/CSS/JS assets. If you need REST endpoints, such as a `GET /health_check` you need to develop and deploy a server application such as ExpressJS or any language/framework you prefer. If you are using Angular Universal, you may have an opportunity to add this endpoint though.